# Is mame ARM compatible?

Tags: emulation, arm

I'm still waiting on my Raspberry Pi, but when I get it, will it be possible to run Mame on it?

I'm not concerned about how it will perform, but I've got my mind set on a project and want to know if it will work in the first place.

Comment: I'm quite interested in this, so I'm going to have a go compiling and let you know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found [this post](http://1337technophile.blogspot.com/2012/03/compiling-xmame-106-on-rasberry-pi.html) which details how to compile xmame for the Pi.

I'm not sure how this will run. Are you planning on outputting sound and video via HDMI?

While you wait for your Pi you can always download a [VirtualBox Image](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=2961) so that you can emulate it and see how things will run.

Answer (score 3):

I've compiled Advmame for the Raspberry Pi, but it is just that little bit too slow to enjoy the classic games on...

Comment: Thanks for your answer James. Could you add a little more detail on how you compiled it? Does it always run slow, or just whilst executing certain tasks?